# Twitter-like splash screen animation in Android

Tags: android, twitter, android-animation

How to achieve effect like Twitter splash screen animation (from iOS Twitter version) in Android application?
There is library https://github.com/callumboddy/CBZSplashView but it is for iOS only.

Comment: For API 21+ devices you can get something similar by using a [Circular Reveal Transition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewAnimationUtils.html) - Check createCircularReveal method

Comment: Thank you but how to do that using API 15? I found https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal but how to connect it with splash screen?

Comment: I have no idea. But looking at the readme it seems that you can call `SupportAnimator animator =
            ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius)`, where you give it the coordinates and a view!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[THis link](https://github.com/ykabaran/TwitterSplash) may be usefull for you just download the code and as per the link suggests
You can create in code:

```
// create and customize the view
SplashView splashView = new SplashView(context);
// the animation will last 0.5 seconds
splashView.setDuration(500);
// transparent hole will look white before the animation
splashView.setHoleFillColor(Color.WHITE);
// this is the Twitter blue color
splashView.setIconColor(Color.rgb(23, 169, 229));
// a Twitter icon with transparent hole in it
splashView.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_twitter);
// remove the SplashView from MainView once animation is completed
splashView.setRemoveFromParentOnEnd(true);
```

or in XML:

```
<com.yildizkabaran.twittersplash.view.SplashView 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yildizkabaran.twittersplash"
    android:id="@+id/splash_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter"
    app:iconColor="@color/twitter_blue"
    app:duration="500"
    app:holeFillColor="@color/white"
    app:removeFromParentOnEnd="true" />
```

then to run the animation, simply call:

--> run the animation and listen to the animation events (listener can be left as null)

```
splashView.splashAndDisappear(new ISplashListener(){
    @Override
    public void onStart(){

}

@Override
public void onUpdate(float completionFraction){

}

@Override
public void onEnd(){

}
```

});`

-Hope you find your answer.

Comment: How to add dependencies to the app.?

Comment: @RahulKushwaha there is no need to add any dependencies just copy paste `SplashView ` class from `GitHub` and add relevant attributes

Comment: @Dinesh thanks brother it works and i understand it clearly.